# SDL system memory rising very very fast on my game

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sdl

This is my code :

```
void apply_start_screen()
{
apply_surface( 0, 0, startingScreenBackground, screen );
apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - startButton->w ) /2, 200, startButton, screen);
apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - infoButton ->w ) /2, 450, infoButton, screen );
message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "In The Jungle!", green );

apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - message->w ) / 2, 25, message, screen );

SDL_Flip( screen );
 }
```

main code ...

```
Mouse start( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - startButton->w ) /2,  200, 200, 200);
```

thats a class that only creates a button using sdl rect and checks if its pressed or not

and the problem which is here :

```
while( quit == false )
{
    apply_start_screen();
if( start.handle_event() == true )
{
    currentState = 1;
}
}
```

current state just goes to the next screen dont worry about it .
The problem is that apply_start_screen() makes system memory increase every time it is used. i dont get it. If you render the same image/text more that one time it uses more memory ? why ? sdl surfaces are dynamicly allocated but still i render the same surface which mean that i dont allocate more memory ? any suggestions ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: TTF_RenderText_Solid returns a new surface. You must free it with SDL_FreeSurface.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! so i should free the SDL_surface *message ? if so on the next call i will not be able to use message again right ?

Comment: Indeed. Though it may be preferable to create it once before the main loop and reuse it every frame by passing it to apply_start_screen. At the moment you're creating a new image on every iteration through the loop for every time start-screen is displayed.

Comment: yeah i changed the code and it worked ! Thanks for your help

Comment: @doynax You are encouraged to post an answer.

Comment: just edited the post with the answer :)

Comment: @KostasRimis Answers do not belong in the question. Please remove the solution and post an answer below.

Comment: ok i just changed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : since TTF_RenderText_Solid returns a surface and SDL_surface is a struct that dynamicly allocats pixels , the problem was that on every frame of while the apply_start_screen function was dynamicly allocating memory. There are 2 ways to fix this:
first create a global SDL_surface *message and do the following :

```
void apply_start_screen()
{
apply_surface( 0, 0, startingScreenBackground, screen );
apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - startButton->w ) /2, 200, startButton, screen);
apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - infoButton ->w ) /2, 450, infoButton, screen );
message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "In The Jungle!", green );

apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - message->w ) / 2, 25, message, screen );

    SDL_FreeSurface( message );
    message = NULL;
 }
```

or simply remove the TTF_RendeText_Solid so no more surfaces are created/returned as here :

```
void apply_start_screen()
{
apply_surface( 0, 0, startingScreenBackground, screen );
apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - startButton->w ) /2, 200, startButton, screen);
apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - infoButton ->w ) /2, 450, infoButton, screen );

apply_surface( ( SCREEN_WIDTH - message->w ) / 2, 25, message, screen );

}
    main...
    message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "In The Jungle!", green );
    rest of program...
```

Hope i helped :)